# Python Fatal error while creating a Sudoku game

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a Sudoku game in python with a solver included. First of all, for some reason, it doesn't show me the procedure of resolving, the window opens only when the board is solved and secondly when i close the window it returns me that python fatal error :Fatal Python error: pygame_parachute: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault
Python runtime state: initialized

That is my code :

```
import time 
import pygame 
from random import *
import numpy as np 

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()

LARGEUR, HAUTEUR = 550, 550
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((LARGEUR, HAUTEUR))
pygame.display.set_caption('Sudoku Game')
Font1 = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 35)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


BLANC = (255, 255, 255)
NOIR = (0, 0, 0)
BLEU = (0,0,255)

def gen_grille():
    grille = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],                      
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],                     
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],                      
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],                     
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],                      
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],                      
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],                      
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],                      
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]                       
]                        
            

    val_debut = 17
    for n in range(val_debut):
        lgn = randint(1, 8)
        cl = randint(1, 8)
        num = randint(1, 9)

        while(not is_possible(grille,lgn,cl,num) or grille[lgn][cl] != 0): 
            lgn = randint(1, 8)
            cl = randint(1, 8)
            num = randint(1, 9)
        
        grille[lgn][cl]= num;

    return list(grille)

def is_possible(grille,lgn,cl,num):
    statut = True
    
    for a in range(9):
        if (grille[a][cl] == num):
            statut = False
    
    for b in range(9):
        if (grille[lgn][b] == num):
            statut = False

    zone_lgn = lgn // 3
    zone_cl = cl // 3
    for a in range(3):
        for b in range(3):
            if(grille[zone_lgn*3 + a][zone_cl*3 + b] == num):
                statut = False
    
    return statut

gen_grille()

grille = gen_grille()
grid_original = [[grille[x][y] for y in range(len(grille[0]))] for x in range(len(grille))]

def draw_new_vals(WIN, position):
    x,y = position[0], position[1]
    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 35)
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if(grid_original[x-1][y-1] != 0):
                    return
                if(event.key == 48): 
                    grille[x-1][y-1] = event.key - 48
                    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, BLANC, (position[0]*50 + 5, position[0]*50+ 5, 40, 40))
                    pygame.display.update()
                    return                
                    
                if(0 < event.key - 48 <10):  
                    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, BLANC, (position[0]*50 + 5, position[1]*50+ 5, 40, 40))
                    value = myfont.render(str(event.key-48), True, (0,0,0))
                    WIN.blit(value, (position[0]*50 +15, position[1]*50))
                    grille[x-1][y-1] = event.key - 48
                    pygame.display.update()
                    return
                return


def draw_strt_vals():
    for x in range(9):
        for y in range(9):
            if(0 < grille[x][y] < 10):
                num = Font1.render(str(grille[x][y]), True, BLEU)
                WIN.blit(num, ((x+1)*50 + 15, (y+1)*50 + 15))


def draw_all():
    WIN.fill(BLANC)

    draw_grille()
    draw_strt_vals()
    
    
    pygame.display.update()



def draw_grille():
    for x in range(10):
        pygame.draw.line(WIN, (NOIR), (50 + 50*x, 50), (50 + 50*x, 500), 2)
        pygame.draw.line(WIN, (NOIR), (50, 50 + 50*x), (500, 50 + 50*x), 2)

    for x in range(10):
        if x % 3 == 0:
            pygame.draw.line(WIN, (NOIR), (50 + 50*x, 50), (50 + 50*x, 500), 4) 
            pygame.draw.line(WIN, (NOIR), (50, 50 + 50*x), (500, 50 + 50*x), 4)

solved = 0
def solver(grille):
    Font1 = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 35)  
    for lgn in range(9):
        for cl in range(9):
            if grille[lgn][cl] == 0:
                for num in range(1,10):
                    if is_possible(grille, lgn, cl, num):
                        grille[lgn][cl] = num
                        pygame.draw.rect(WIN, BLANC, ((cl+1)*50 + 5, (lgn+1)*50+ 5,40 ,40))
                        value = Font1.render(str(num), True, (0,0,0))
                        WIN.blit(value, ((cl+1)*50 +15,(lgn+1)*50))
                        pygame.display.update()

                        solver(grille)
                        
                        global solved
                        if(solved == 1):
                            return
                        grille[lgn][cl] = 0
                        pygame.draw.rect(WIN, BLANC, ((lgn+1)*50 + 5, (cl+1)*50+ 5,40 ,40))
                        pygame.display.update()
                return               
    solved = 1
        

def main():
    pygame.init()
    clock.tick(60)
    marche = True

    for i in range(0, len(grille[0])):
        for j in range(0, len(grille[0])):
            if(0<grille[i][j]<10):
                value = Font1.render(str(grille[i][j]), True, BLEU)
                WIN.blit(value, ((j+1)*50 + 15, (i+1)*50 ))
    pygame.display.update()

    solver(grille)
    while marche: 

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == 1:
                m_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()           
                draw_new_vals(WIN, (m_pos[0]//50, m_pos[1]//50))

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                
                return

        
        
        draw_all()

main()       

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

    main()
```

Comment: why do you call `main()` twice ?

Comment: you need to break this into parts:  [1] the board, [2] solving.   https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: How do I do that ? I'm still learning the language

Comment: i expect you want the solver to run when a button is pressed (or something like that) ?

Comment: Yes exactly but that doesn't work either I tried to implement a : if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: if event.type == pygame.K_a slover(WIN) but that doesn't work

Comment: ....but i see that you just call solver in main.  So it will just run automatically when that line of code is reached.  it is not contingent on anything.  needs an `if` statement or a `button` or something to invoke it.

Comment: if i just add  in main() : for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.K_a:
            solver(WIN) when i press "a" nothing happens at all